# js устанавливаю cookie на год, но они сбрасываются раньше

Tags: javascript, php, cookie

При посещении сайта пользователь видит окно с предупреждением, о том, что здесь исользуются cookie + кнопка OK, для закрытия этого окна. При клике на кнопку срабатывает js. В течение примерно месяца данное окно не появляется, но потом снова выскакивает, т.к. cookie слетели. Слетают они на компе и на телефоне, у меня браузер сафари. В чем может быть проблема: в коде или в браузере?

```
<?php
// если cookie не установлены
if($_COOKIE["usescooksite"] != "on"){ ?>
     <div>На сайте используются файлы cookie.</div>
     <div class="cookie_bl">
         <button id="cookie_close" onclick="click_accept">OK</button>
     </div><?php
} ?>

<script>
    cookiewin = document.getElementsByClassName('cookie_bl')[0];

   // закрываем окно по клику на btn OK
   document.getElementById("cookie_close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    cookiewin.style.display="none";    

    // записываем cookie на 1 год, что бы не показывать информацию о куки
    let date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);
    
    document.cookie = "usescooksite=on; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();               
});
</script>
```

Comment: js cookie и php cookie это не одно и то же

Comment: Вы в инструментах разработчика в браузере смотрели на сколько поставлены куки?

Comment: 1. InDevX, "js cookie и php cookie это не одно и то же" - т.е. $_COOKIE["usescooksite"] от php не понимает date js? и где об этом почитать?

Comment: 2. 
Alexey Ten, к моему стыду я не нашел в сафари, где установить срок жизни cookie. В инете вообще говорится о том, что apple и googl вводят «санкции» для cookies

Comment: в js время ставится в милисекундах, в php в секундах. Проверьте, нет ли у вас разницы ровно в 1000 раз

Comment: Alex Khonko, спасибо за коммент, проверю